# How to plot a histogram using Matplotlib in Python taking probability?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have taking probability using randint function. but i am facing issue in histogram to show my probability. [image: Also attaching snap which i am getting error]
my Probability output like this.

```
{60: 0.013, 6: 0.016, 99: 0.01, 25: 0.006, 45: 0.017, 51: 0.009, 72: 0.011, 8: 0.015, 10: 0.015, 82: 0.011, 50: 0.014, 43: 0.012, 52: 0.011, 74: 0.015, 12: 0.015, 39: 0.01, 89: 0.014, 7: 0.009}
```

My python code.

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hist = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=1000)
counts = Counter(hist)
total = sum(counts.values())
hist = {k:v/total for k,v in counts.items()}


num_bins = 10
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(hist, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
#plt.plot(bins, hist, 'r--')
plt.xlabel('Grades')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.title('Histogram of Students Grade')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why is this tagged R?

Comment: It was mistake. i comment this `plt.plot(bins, hist, 'r--')` i need just my Probabilty Histogram. where the issue occurs ?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Can you show us the plot you are getting now and explain what it is that you want to look different?

Comment: @FranciscaConcha-Ramírez when you run this code i am getting this error `'<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'float'`. and the graph was empty.

Comment: @FranciscaConcha-Ramírez i think their will use `Dict` and `float` function to seprate the values first then do the Histogram. like {60: 0.013, 6: 0.016, 99: 0.01} do you understand my issue ?

Answer (score 2):

If you just comment out `plt.plot(bins, hist, 'r--')` you get this plot:

[image]

Is this what you are looking for?

If you want to make use of `n`, `bins` and `patches` you can [refer to this example](https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/api/histogram_demo.html) in the Matplotlib documentation.

Comment: Actually, i need just my Probabilty Histogram.. can you Edit my code ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Isn't this exactly what the graph shows?

Comment: this is my output of probabilty `{60: 0.013, 6: 0.016, 99: 0.01, 25: 0.006, 45: 0.017, 51: 0.009, 72: 0.011, 8: 0.015, 10: 0.015, 82: 0.011}` now i want graph in x-axis and y-axis. like `60 in y-axis and 0.013 in x-axis` in graph.

Comment: i am facing this error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'float'`